# Let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous at all points. Show that for each interval $I \subset D$, $f(I) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Can someone help me with this proof.

I tried the following:

WTP: $\forall I \subset D$, $f(I)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval.

$f(I) =  \{ f(x)| x \in I \}$

proof. Let $I = [a,b]$ an interval walog.

$I \subset D$. Let $a, b \in I$

Let $f(a), f(b) \in I$ (walog. $f(a) < f(b)$)

walog. Let $f(a) \leq y \leq f(b)$ using the intermediate value theorem $\Rightarrow \exists x \in [a,b]$

such that $f(x) = y$.

$ \therefore \forall y$  such that $f(a) \leq y \leq f(b) \Rightarrow f(a) \leq f(x) \leq f(b)$, $x \in I$

$ \therefore  \exists [f(a), f(b)] \subset f(I)$

WTP: $f(I) \subset [f(a), f(b)]$

To be honest I got to this point, but I don't know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Intervals are connected sets and continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets. Are yo familiar with Intermediate Value Porperty of continuous functions?

Comment: Assuming $I$ is a closed interval, your proof will work if you use the Extreme value theorem. $f(I) = [m, M]$, where $m$ and $M$ are the minimum and maximum values of $f$ on $[a, b]$. If $I$ is not a closed interval, $f(I)$ need not be a closed interval (it could be unbounded).

Comment: FYI - "WLOG" stands for "Without Loss Of Generality". Notice that there is no "a" anywhere between the "W" and the "L". So "walog" does not work as a substitute acronym, and leaves people wondering what you mean.

Comment: Also, it is only appropriate to use WLOG when you have a situation where there are two or more possible cases, but it is only necessary to examine one of the cases, because the others reduce to it in a very obvious way (usually, just by exchanging the meaning of labels). Only one of the three "walog"s you have is appropriate ($f(a) < f(b)$). In the first, $I$ was already given as an interval, and you are introducing $a,b$. The only assumption made was that $I$ is closed & bounded, but that is most definitely **with** loss of generality. In the other there is only one case to consider.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Mason's comment, you are assuming that $I$ is a *closed and bounded* interval. But there are 10 different types of interval, Closed and bounded is only one of them.

Intervals can be characterized as the sets $C$ with the property:

- for any $u, v \in C$ with $u < v$, if $u < x < v$, then $x \in C$ as well.

If you have that characterization of intervals, then your task is much easier.  Because all you need to show is that if $u,v \in I$ with $f(u) < f(v)$, then for any $y$ with $f(u) < y < f(v)$, there is some $x \in I$ with $f(x) = y$, which follows from the intermediate value theorem.

But almost certainly, you do not have that characterization available, as almost no one ever gives it. so you have to examine each of the ten possible intervals and show that they all work:
$$[a,b], [a, b), (a, b], (a,b), [a,\infty), (a, \infty), (-\infty, b], (-\infty, b), (-\infty, \infty), \emptyset$$
(whether the empty set is an interval is something people may differ on).

In all cases, you need to show $f(I) = \{\ [\text{ or }(\ \} \inf f(I), \sup f(I)\{\ ]\text{ or })\ \}$.